# Whats wrong with this code?

Tags: java

I am new in to learn java please help me to resolve the issue. whats wrong with my code???
please help me when i run this code then i find the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

```
public class SearchForFile {

static File file;
String[] args = null;
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                // Open the file c:\test.txt as a buffered reader

                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));



                // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current line.

                int linecount = 0;

                    String line;



                // Let the user know what we are searching for

                System.out.println("Searching for " + args[0] + " in file...");



                // Loop through each line, stashing the line into our line variable.

                while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)

                {

                        // Increment the count and find the index of the word

                        linecount++;

                        int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);



                        // If greater than -1, means we found the word

                        if (indexfound > -1) {

                             System.out.println("Word was found at position " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);

                        }

                }



                // Close the file after done searching

                bf.close();

            }      

            catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());

            }

            }}
```

In this code I find this error kindle help me to resolve the issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at ForFile.main(ForFile.java:39)
```

Comment: Your title is wrong too.

Comment: You aren't passing any command line argument, so you can't access `args[0]`.

Comment: Which line is line 39? Also, note that the comment *// Open the file c:\test.txt as a buffered reader* contradicts the next line.

Comment: In your `while` loop `linecount` is simply being incremented whereas the check in `while` condition happens to be on `line` variable.

Comment: have you passed any command line argument ?

Comment: no i didn't pass any command line argument

Comment: i want to pass hard coded argument.. how i pass hard coded argument???

Answer (score 3):

Always be defensive, you should design your code so it shouldn't fail, and if it does it exists gracefully, or fails gracefully.

There are two ways you can solve the above problem.

**First:** Check the size of the `arg` before accessing it

```
if (arg.length == 1) //Do Stuff with arg[0]
```

You can change the above if statment to solve it the way you like, so say you require the user to input to enter three arguments and without three arguments your program can not continue. try:

```
if (arg.length != 3) //Stop the loop and tell the users that they need 3 args
```

**Second:** Encapsulate the `arg[0]` in a try an catch, so Inside your `while` loop

```
try
{
    int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);
    linecount++;
    if (indexfound > -1)
        System.out.println("Word was found at position " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);

}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.out.println("arg[0] index is not initialized");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we don't know what line is it exactly, but I guess it's happening in this line:

```
System.out.println("Searching for " + args[0] + " in file...");
```

It happens because you don't pass any program arguments to the application when you start it. Try:

```
java SearchForFile word
```

Comment: then brother what i do ? please help me i am new in learning java

Comment: Well, I told you how to run the application. If you are running from command line type this: `java SearchForFile word`, if you are running from Eclipse then `Run as > Run configurations ... > Arguments > Program arguments` and just add `word` or whatever argument you want

Comment: yes its working brother but i want that i give the search word hard coded ??? then what i do now ? pls help me

Comment: Instead of `args` use `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` Then you read the input with `String searchWord = in.readLine();` and use `searchWord` later on in the code instead of `args[0]`.

Comment: no brother i dont want to give the search word everytime by write in console. i want to give 1 specific word hard coded and then everytime when i run that program then i find only that specific word. this is my point

Comment: Then instead of `args[0]` or `Scanner` give a variable, e.g. `String searchWord = "something";` And instead of `args[0]` use `searchWord`. Define it just before `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Did that fix the problem? Hope it did. Accept?